# Meaning of topology axiom

Tags: general-topology

We can define (and to my opinion this is the best way to do it) a topology in terms of neighbourhoods.
We call a topology on a set $X$ a family $(\mathcal{V}_x)_{x\in X}$ of sets in $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ which verifies for all $x$ :

- $\mathcal{V}_x$ is a filter on $X$
- $\forall V\in\mathcal{V}_x,x\in V$
- $\forall V\in\mathcal{V}_x,\exists W\in \mathcal{V}_x, W\subset V\wedge \forall y\in W,W\in \mathcal{V}_y$

I do understand the first two axioms. They make a lot of sense to me. But I do not understand the last one. I believe it is some sort of compatibility axioms for the neighbourhoods of different points.

What meaning do you give to the third axiom ? I do not want an answer of this kind : "without it, such or such axiom of open sets would not be true". But rather something meaningful.

Comment: The last axiom tells you that any point has at least an open neighborhood (a set is open if it contains a neighborhood of any of its points, with this approach). So it's the last axiom that guarantees any union of open sets is open.

Comment: As written, the third isn't useful, $W=\varnothing$ would be a legitimate choice. It should be $$\bigl(\forall V \in \mathcal{V}_x\bigr)\bigl(\exists W\in \mathcal{V}_x\bigr)\bigl(\forall y\in W\bigr)\bigl(V \in \mathcal{V}_y\bigr).$$

Comment: @Daniel Fisher : No, $W$ cannot be empty because $y\in W$ thanks to the second axiom.

Comment: @Florian No, if $W=\varnothing$, the $\forall y\in W, W\in \mathcal{V}_y$ is vacuously true.

Comment: @Daniel Fisher : My apologies, you were quite right. I made an edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, these axioms are about the (not necessarily open) neighbourhoods of points.  Given such a system $\{ \mathcal{V}_x \}_{x \in X}$, we will call the sets in $\mathcal{V}_x$ the *neighbourhoods* of $x$.  (Since a neighbourhood of $x$ should actually contain $x$, this is where the second axiom comes in.)

We would then define the *open sets* to be those $U \subseteq X$ such that $U \in \mathcal{V}_x$ for each $x \in U$.

The fact that the $\mathcal{V}_x$ are filters then implies that the family of open sets is closed under finite intersections and arbitrary unions.

The third axiom them says that every neighbourhood of $x$ includes an *open* neighbourhood of $x$ as a subset, which would then imply that the neighbourhoods of $x$ are exactly those $A \subseteq X$ such that $x \in \mathrm{Int} (A)$.  (It also implies that the family of open neighbourhoods is a *filter base* for $\mathcal{V}_x$.)